# Forming n-grams for a dataframe (numbers) in python

Tags: python, pandas, n-gram

I found many posts explaining **n-grams** in words. However, I need to apply n-grams (n = 2 or 3) on a dataframe that has integer numbers of n x m. For example: Consider the below dataframe (3 x 5)

```
df = 

1, 2, 3, 4, 5

6, 7, 8, 9, 10

11, 12, 13, 14, 15
```

I need to apply **bigram** and **trigram** on df.

I tried this code, but it does not work properly

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    row = list(str(df.iloc[i,:]))
    print("row:  ", row)
    bigrams = [b for l in row for b in zip(l.split(" ")[:-1], l.split(" ")[1:])]
    print(bigrams)
```

If the input is `df = [10,20,30,40,50,60,...]`

Expected output

Bigram

`(10,20)(20,30)(30,40)(40,50)...`

Trigram

`(10,20,30)(20,30,40)(30,40,50)...`

Comment: Considering your example input, what would be the expected output?

Comment: For example, for each row of df, if the row is  [ 60, 78, 56, 78, 60, ... ], the tri-gram features are: (60, 78, 56), (78, 56, 78), (56, 78, 60), etc.; the bi-gram features are:  (60, 78), (78, 56), (56, 78), (78, 60), etc. Note: we do not need the brackets.

Comment: I get the general logic, you need to use `itertools.combinations`, but what about the specifics? Do you need new rows? A list of the n-grams? Please provide the exact input as [DataFrame constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and the same for the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`nltk.ngrams`](https://tedboy.github.io/nlps/generated/generated/nltk.ngrams.html#nltk-ngrams):

```
from nltk.util import ngrams

# for bigrams
for a in df.values:
    print(list(ngrams(a, n=2)))
```

---

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
[(6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9), (9, 10)]
[(11, 12), (12, 13), (13, 14), (14, 15)]
```

---

For trigrams set `n=3`:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5)]
[(6, 7, 8), (7, 8, 9), (8, 9, 10)]
[(11, 12, 13), (12, 13, 14), (13, 14, 15)]
```

Comment: Thanks, however, I need just numbers inside a list without parenthesis, e.g., [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 9, 8, 9, 10]
[11, 12, 13, 12, 13, 14, 13, 14, 15]